# converting screen coordinates to geopoint

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm trying to port an app from `googlemap 2.2` to `osmdroid 3.0.8`.
I'm stuck with the following code in my MapView:

```
Projection proj = getProjection();
GeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);
GeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
```

With osmdroid, topLeft is always at north pole.

Is there a different way to handle that in OSM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OsmDroid you use mapView.getScreenRect to find the top left of the screen.

Comment: I tried `Rect l_rect = p_proj.getScreenRect();` but l_rect.top and l_rect.left return 0

Comment: I have no `getScreenRect()` in `org.osmdroid.views.Mapview`

Comment: My mistake. I had a problem with eclipse. Now I can use the method.